# Build issue with SDL2_image and XCODE

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl-2

At the moment I'm trying to learn game development with SDL. I've installed the SDL2 library and SDL2_image library with homebrew and coding with Xcode.

A problem I keep encountering is that everytime I build the project, I keep seeing the same SIGABRT message:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x10006ded4 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
0x10006ded9 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x10006dedc <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10006dede <+10>: jae    0x10006dee8               ; <+20>
0x10006dee0 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10006dee3 <+15>: jmp    0x10006c408               ; cerror_nocancel
0x10006dee8 <+20>: retq   
0x10006dee9 <+21>: nop    
0x10006deea <+22>: nop    
0x10006deeb <+23>: nop
```

If I only add SDL2's library, the project builds and run normally, but the moment I add SDL2_image, the project just stops functioning. The libraries are linked to the .dylib in /usr/local/Cellar.

Can someone point out what is the cause of this issue?

Thank you.

Edit*
Below is the main function of my code. It is from this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrWQsuDT3NE&list=PLhfAbcv9cehhkG7ZQK0nfIGJC_C-wSLrx&index=4&t=1s&ab_channel=Let%27sMakeGames

```
#include "Game.hpp"

Game *game = nullptr;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) { 
    game = new Game();

    game->init("My Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

    while (game->running()) {
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }

    game->clean();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit and post your C++ code ? (`main()` function only)

Comment: Edited with more info, thank you for taking a look at it!